# How to close IIS Worker Process

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2008-sp1, w3wp, worker-process

I was trying to install Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on my machine and I encountered this issue.
[image: Problem screenshot]

I looked it up, it looks like IIS Worker Process is some kind of    [w3wp.exe](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125113/How-to-use-IIS-Manager-to-get-Worker-Processes-w3w), so I looked into my Windows Task Manager and found out w3wp.exe is not running. I also took a look at my Worker Processes in IIS Manager and it wasn't started either. So, how do I close this application so I can continue my install or is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. In IIS Manager -> Application pool, stop all applications
2. Run CMD as administrator, and type `iisreset -noforce`

Comment: I didn't see an option for "stop all applications" but this worked by going through one by one and stopping them.